# Moving under the influence of a vector field

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, differential-equations

I have a continuously varying vector field $v(p)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a particle
at point $p$ in the plane that can move in a direction $u(p)$ as long as $u(p)$ is
turned at most $\pi/2$ left of $v(p)$.  So at any point $p$, the particle can move in
a quarter-circle of directions: from $v(p)$ to $v(p)$ rotated $90^\circ$ counterclockwise.

I would like to identify the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ reachable from a given start point $p_0$
under this constraint.
For example, suppose the vector field is determined by a rotation about a fixed center $c$.
Then the reachable points are just those in the disk centered on $c$ with radius $|p_0 - c|$:

     [image: Vector Field]
I can write down equations, in terms of dot- and cross-product, but they are not revealing to me.

> **Q**. Is there some clean formulation of this problem that suggests a 
>   computationally feasible identification
>   of the reachable points?

Thanks for any insights/ideas!

Comment: What should your constraint mean at a zero of the vector field?  If you don't allow zeros, I'd say you have a Lorentz structure on the plane, and you're asking about the causal relationships between points. 

Comment: @Ryan: Good question!  I must allow zeros, for rotations about a point are among my vector fields.  I guess then $u(p)$ must also be zero: the particle stops and stays there.

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks for the "Lorentz structure" hint; that connection did not occur to me.

Comment: Okay, then you're looking at the causal structure on the plane minus the zeros of the vector field / Lorentz structure. 

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a distribution except that instead of having linear subspaces you have cones.  There's this paper: [Langerock, "Conic Distributions and Accessible Sets,"](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10883-007-9034-4) but it sounds an awful lot like your question (and I wonder if that's where you're starting from in the first place!).  It also doesn't say anything about the computability of the accessible set, though they do provide some characterization.

Comment: @fuzzytron: I am starting from a completely different place, but this paper and its references to the literature on *accessible sets* is just what I need.  Thanks!